# Cannot find and read file in python setup to package my project

Tags: python, package, python-wheel

I am not experienced with python packaging. I am trying to package my project with the command python3 -m build. In the setup file I need to open some files, among them the VERSION file, but I get the error that they cannot be found.

This is how I open it in my setup.py file

```
here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
about = {}
with io.open(os.path.join(here, 'my-project', 'VERSION')) as f:
     _version = f.read().strip()
     about["__version__"] = _version
```

The error I get is:

```
/private/var/folders/pk/r6xddw312z9d5_rfggl0d5pw0000gn/T/build-via-sdist-trdyv1sv/my-project-0.0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
 main()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
 json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
 return hook(config_settings)
File "/private/var/folders/pk/r6xddw312z9d5_rfggl0d5pw0000gn/T/build-env 5euz44zr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 154, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
 return self._get_build_requires(
File "/private/var/folders/pk/r6xddw312z9d5_rfggl0d5pw0000gn/T/build-env 5euz44zr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 135, in _get_build_requires
 self.run_setup()
File "/private/var/folders/pk/r6xddw312z9d5_rfggl0d5pw0000gn/T/build-env 5euz44zr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
 exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
File "setup.py", line 49, in <module>
 with io.open(os.path.join(here, 'my-project', 'VERSION' )) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/pk/r6xddw312z9d5_rfggl0d5pw0000gn/T/build-via-sdist-trdyv1sv/my-project-0.0.1/my-project/VERSION'
```

Also what is the path

```
 /private/var/folders/pk/r6xddw312z9d5_rfggl0d5pw0000gn/T/build-via-sdist-trdyv1sv/
```

where the file cannot be found?

My final result is that the build folder and the .egg-info files are created correctly with the tar.gz file packaged but not the wheel file. Therefore I assume there is some issue with wheel

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the extra `my-project` reference on this line.

```py
with io.open(os.path.join(here, 'my-project', 'VERSION')) as f:
```

What does this give you:

```py
with io.open(os.path.join(here, 'VERSION')) as f:
```

What you can also try is creating a file called `_version.py` in your main folder (next to setup.py).
Then simply at the top of the file add
`__version__ = '1.107.7'`.
You can now import it in your setup.py as so:

```py
from _version import __version__

setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=__version__,
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I need my-project because it is where the version file is located. I have the same problem also with opening the requirement files. What is the /private/var/folders/pk/r6xddw312z9d5_rfggl0d5pw0000gn/T/build-via-sdist-trdyv1sv/ path where it cannot find the file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you provide a pastebin of what you get when you run the two things I mentioned above?

Comment: from _version import __version__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'

You are in the wrong way. I was saying that I have problems in opening and reading also another file

Comment: Yes I believe you. However, could you please provide a pastebin of the command you are executing and the full logs. It will definitely help me or anyone else for that matter who is trying to help you.

Comment: Excuse me, what is a pastebin? Also _version is not a module and cannot be called. It is just a file. So cannot do much more with your suggestion. The commands I am running and the errors are all pasted in the post. Thanks

Comment: A passtebin is a copy of your entire logs uploaded to a public site like pastebin.com. The full logs will allow us to inspect it in more details.

Answer (score 0):

`python3 -m build` may not include non .py files in your tar file, that is why you are getting a "file not found error" when running it.

Notice that the error occurs when `build` tries to install your package as a verification step.

You can solve this by adding a `MANIFEST.in` file to your package root. The content of this file is just a list of non .py files that you want to add to your .tar file. For instance

```
include LICENSE
include requirements.txt
include my-project/VERSION
```

Also, set `include_package_data=True` in your `setup.py`.

You can read more about this [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html).